# Get Decimal Number From String in C

Tags: c, stdin

Let's say I am reading in the following string:

`0.2 0.2 Jefferson Thomas`

What I need to do is make some coordinate point out of the (0.2,0.2), and then store the name separately. Other strings, though, may have more names (3+).

What is the best way to extract the 0.2's and store them?

Comment: The best way is to open a C book or tutorial and start to learn. Have you done the chapters on reading and parsing input? For starters you can use `scanf` to read input into variables.

Comment: I did, I just have been on this assignment for so long that I may need to simply walk away from the computer and recharge, I honestly forgot scanf even exists. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the sscanf and related family of functions.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm

```
float x,y;

sscanf(your_str, "%f %f %s %s", &x, &y, first, last );
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to extract the 0.2's and store them?

The best way begins with using `fgets()` and not `scanf()`.

Read the *line* of input with `fgets()` to form a *string* and then parse with `sscanf()`.

```
double x,y;
char name[100];
if (sscanf(buf, "%lf %lf %99[^\n]", &x, &y, name) == 3) {
  //Yeah, successful read
```

`%99[^\n]` reads up to 99 non-`'\n'` characters.